# How to run playbook api in Ansible with vault

Tags: python, ansible

I have a playbook with vault, and I can run it through:

```
ansible-playbook info.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

Now, I want to run my playbook api in Ansible. The answer in [How to run playbook api in Ansible v2 with vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537303/how-to-run-playbook-api-in-ansible-v2-with-vault) said that we can set

```
loader = DataLoader()
loader.set_vault_password('mypass')
```

in 2.2.0.0 API, and I also set these in my api，but it doesn't work. The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 63, in <module>
    playbook.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 82, in run
    pb = Playbook.load(playbook_path, variable_manager=self._variable_manager, loader=self._loader)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 54, in load
    pb._load_playbook_data(file_name=file_name, variable_manager=variable_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 78, in _load_playbook_data
    ds = self._loader.load_from_file(os.path.basename(file_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 130, in load_from_file
    (b_file_data, show_content) = self._get_file_contents(file_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 206, in _get_file_contents
    data = self._vault.decrypt(data, filename=b_file_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 561, in decrypt
    plaintext, vault_id = self.decrypt_and_get_vault_id(vaulttext, filename=filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 617, in decrypt_and_get_vault_id
    _matches = match_secrets(self.secrets, vault_id_matchers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 456, in match_secrets
    matches = [(vault_id, secret) for vault_id, secret in secrets if vault_id in target_vault_ids]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Then I change the

```
loader.set_vault_password('mypass')
```

to

```
loader.set_vault_secrets([('default','mypass')])
```

But it doesn't work either. The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 63, in <module>
    playbook.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py", line 82, in 
    pb = Playbook.load(playbook_path, variable_manager=self._variable_manager, loader=self._l
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 54, in load
    pb._load_playbook_data(file_name=file_name, variable_manager=variable_manager)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 78, in _load_pla
    ds = self._loader.load_from_file(os.path.basename(file_name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 130, in load_fr
    (b_file_data, show_content) = self._get_file_contents(file_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 206, in _get_fi
    data = self._vault.decrypt(data, filename=b_file_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 561, in dec
    plaintext, vault_id = self.decrypt_and_get_vault_id(vaulttext, filename=filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 638, in dec
    b_plaintext = this_cipher.decrypt(b_vaulttext, vault_secret)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py", line 1344, in de
    b_password = secret.bytes
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'bytes'
```

I try to change the line

```
b_password = secret.bytes
```

in file `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py` to

```
b_password = secret
```

then the api works normally. But I think it's not a good way to basically solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `VaultSecret` class instead of string password:

```
from ansible.module_utils._text import to_bytes
from ansible.parsing.vault import VaultSecret

loader.set_vault_secrets([('default',VaultSecret(_bytes=to_bytes('123456')))])
```

Comment: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/f8d2f0ac44f3e7a68277631bf4d464ed8b397832/lib/ansible/cli/__init__.py#L294:L308